# Switch in Internet Explorer from HTML5 back to Flash Player in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

As of August 6 2015 (even though this was implemented before), YouTube now defaults to HTML5 instead of Flash. Although this make it work on more devices, there are limitations such as longer loading times, higher resolutions are not supported on all videos, etc.

I'm currently using Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1. How do I switch back to using Flash player for viewing YouTube videos?

Comment: You should add a link to the YouTube notice on this matter. Flash is still default for me at this moment (on Aug. 5). Of course Flash plug-in must be active.

Comment: Cleat your cache, cookies, etc.

Comment: is this still an issue?